# find the max between 0 and a sum of an unsigned int with a signed int

Tags: rust, type-conversion, max

I'm trying to write a function which will take an X position and an offset. This offset can be either negative or positive so I need it to be signed. So if I pass it `X = 0` and `ofs = -3` I need the function to set `X` to `0`, also, or if I pass it `X = 0`, `ofs = 6` and `uppr_lmt = 5` I need it set it to `5`

```rs
fn test(x: &mut u32, ofs: i32, uppr_lmt: u32) {
    use std::cmp::max;

    if ofs < 0 {
        x = max(0, x + ofs);
    } else {
        x = max(uppr_lmt, x + ofs);
    }
}
```

However, in this code rust complains about adding an `i32` to an `&mut u32` and `0` and `uppr_lmt` not being of type `&mut u32`. How can I go about fixing this? I'm still fairly new to Rust and I'm not used to type conversions.

Comment: Think about it: if the result of the sum is negative, u32 can't hold it. If it's > 2^31-1, i32 can't hold it. I don't know about rust, but C you would use a wider type than either, and it would have to be signed off course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is returning a u32 rather than mutating x value. Note that we are having extra conversions to i64 because in an i32, the -3 is going to be considered greater than 0 because of how negative numbers are stored (MSB is 1 for negatives while MSB is taken as 2 power for u32). Note that I have used min here for else case because otherwise, for 0,5,6 passed to function, it returns 6 because max of 5 and 6 is 6 which is not what you expected from your question

```
 fn test(x: u32, ofs: i32, uppr_lmt: u32) -> u32 {
        use std::cmp::{max,min};
        let y;
        if ofs < 0 {
            y = max(0, x as i64 + ofs as i64);
        } else {
            y = min(uppr_lmt as i64, x as i64 + ofs as i64);
        }
        y as u32
 }
```

Instead of i64, you can also use i32 like this assuming inputs are in i32 range and not u32 range (if the number plus offset is less than 2^31 - 1 only)

```
fn test(x: u32, ofs: i32, uppr_lmt: u32) -> u32 {
    use std::cmp::{max,min};
    let y;
    if ofs < 0 {
        y = max(0, x as i32+ ofs);
    } else {
        y = min(uppr_lmt as i32, x as i32+ ofs);
    }
    y as u32
}
```